# Auth0 swift4 failing to handle gist scope

Tags: swift, scope, auth0, gist

I am trying to use Auth0 to authorise a my app to allow Gist comments.
I am not able to get "gist" scope back.

I have configured Auth0 account correctly.  Also Github account correct and everything is setup.

My login code is as follows.

```
            Auth0
            .webAuth()
            .scope("gist")
            .audience("https://pjdavis1970.eu.auth0.com/userinfo")
            .start {
                switch $0 {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                case .success(let credentials):
                    credentialsManager.store(credentials: credentials)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        AppData.sharedInstance.setLoggedIn(loggedIn: true)
                        self.setButtonStatus()
                    }
                }
        }
```

This is returning nil in scopes.  This means I am unable to use gist api to post comments.  Any ideas?

Comment: In order to assist, we at Auth0 would need to know a lot more info, specifically how you've setup the scope in Auth0, that you're assigning the scope to the user on login, and various other variables. We encourage you to ask over in our community.auth0.com to enable others in the community to answer your question.

Comment: Sounds good asking in the community but when you reposnd within 10 minutes in here yet in your own community its sat there for at least 8 hours and no one has responded I dont hold much confidence